# Cannot add a rectangle using svg.js in pixi.js

Tags: pixi.js

Here I want to add a rectangle using svg.js in pixi.js but unable to do it and the error I got.

```
import { SVG } from '@svgdotjs/svg.js'      
import { Rect } from "@svgdotjs/svg.js"      
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'           

let app= new PIXI.Application({         
    width:256,         
    height:256      
});      

document.body.appendChild(app.view); 
    
let rectangle=new PIXI.Graphics();    
let rect = new Rect().size(100, 100).attr({ fill: '#f06',stroke: '#000'});     

PIXI.loader.add('rect').load(setup);     

function setup() {         
    let rectan=new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.loader.resources['rect'].texture);         
    app.stage.addChild(rectan);     
}
```

> uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined at Object.parcelRequire.index.js.@svgdotjs/svg.js